# Python: adding comments to specific cell using Drive API

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to automate some simple updating of a Google spreadsheet and I'm using the [`gspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) library to do so. One task that is critical and not currently supported by `gspread` is the ability to add comments to a specific cell (there's [an open issue](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/50) for this and even a gist solution but I was getting a `404` error when trying to use it).

I know that the Google Drive API (v3) supports adding comments as [described here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments), but I'm having issues with authenticating and could use some help.

### What I have/know:

I have already setup the OAuth 2.0 and registered for the API through Google, as well as have the `client_secret.json` in my directory, but my knowledge of web requests and responses is limited so going through the Drive API documentation hardly makes sense. I know in order to create the comments I will have to make use of anchors and specify the cell location using column/row numbers.

### What I'm stuck on:

When using the Google API Explorer, I'm getting a `400` error with the message: `The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.` How can I make the POST request using my authentication? I think from there I'd be able to actually add the comments myself.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm getting a 400 error with the message: The 'fields' parameter is required for this method**

The error is asking for a property which you want returned (these properties are listed in [Drive API files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files)).

You can just place ' * ' to indicate you want it to return a complete response. That's the quick fix.